# How can trace if someone successfully remotely accessed my Mac?

Tags: macos, remote-desktop

On my home network, I have a headless mini-mac that I use as a media, plex and security cameras server. I had screen and file sharing enabled, so that I can control it from my regular iMac, since no mouse, keyboard and screen is connected to mini-mac. It is connected to my home wifi and also to my regular mac via thunderbolt connection.

My router had port forwarding enabled for that mini-mac so that I can access cameras from outside.

Yesterday, I was working on my regular mac when suddenly my screen moved to the "login screen". I also noticed the screenshare icon was connected and when I hovered over it, it was my mini-mac ip address. I tried to shut down everything ASAP, mac and mini mac, then restarted and disabled screen sharing and remote login on the regular mac.

What steps do I need to take to confirm or rule out, via logs and queries, that someone was able to:

1. Gain access to my network
2. Successfully log into my mini-mac
3. From mini-mac, successfully gain access to my iMac
4. If any of the above items, for how long until uncovered?
5. If they were able to access files, programs, etc.

Basically, I want to assess if indeed I was "hacked" and if so, to what extent.

Thank you!

Comment: - Which port are being forwarded ?
- A list of the listening port of your global ip and mini-mac ip would help you having a precise answer. (search "nmap osx" on the internet)

Comment: 5900, 5901 and 8000, 8001 were enabled.

Answer (score 3):

So your home network should be something like this:

```
                                          +--------------+ 
                          Cameras<------->+  Cam server  +-+
                                          +-------+------+ |   
                                                  |        |
                                                  |        |
+--------------+     +--------------+   wifi/eth  |        |
| The Internet +-----+ ISP's router +-------------+        | Thunderbolt
+--------------+     +--------------+             |        |
                                                  |        |
                                                  |        |
                                          +-------+------+ |
                                          |     iMac     +-+
                                          +-------+------+
```

**Analyze**

> 1. Gain access to my network

You want to check the network logs of the following 3 endpoints:

- The router (Port 5900, 5901)
- The cam server (Port 8000, 8001)
- The iMac (thunderbolt Connection activities)

If you remember when the event occurred, and you know how to read a pcap file you can diagnose what happened.

> 2. Successfully log into my mini-mac

On your cam server, check the entry of those log files (App/Utilities/Console):

`/var/log/osxvnc.log`

`/var/log/secure.log`

`/var/log/system.log`

> 3. From mini-mac, successfully gain access to my iMac

On your iMac, check the entry of those log files:

`/var/log/system.log`

Typing `last` & `last username` in the command prompt might show some useful info.

---

**Additional information**

A VNC server can be bruteforced, look at this [example](https://www.offensive-security.com/metasploit-unleashed/scanner-vnc-auxiliary-modules/) using metasploit and vnc_login module. For preventing it, You can add one of those 2 security layers:

- Adopt a strong password policy with 12 characters as minimum length.

> 1. the use of both upper-case and lower-case letters (case sensitivity)
> 2. inclusion of one or more numerical digits inclusion of special characters, such as @, #, $
> 3. prohibition of words found in a password
>      blacklist
> 4. prohibition of words found in the user's personal information
> 5. prohibition of use of company name or an abbreviation
> 6. prohibition of passwords that match the format of calendar dates, license plate numbers, telephone numbers, or other common numbers
>
>    source [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Password_policy)

- Step up a level by not using a login/password Authentication.

You can find a walkthrough [here](https://www.katescomment.com/how-to-secure-mac-osx-screen-sharing-with-ssh-tunnelling/)

---

**Edit 1** : A successful attacker with enough privilege will delete some log entries ( if he knows what he is doing)

---

**Edit 2, (answering comments)** :

> Also, what specific info should I look for in the logs ?

**router:** Time & Ip address, Ask yourself those questions:

- Which IP address has connected to my network when i was home ? You also want to know the global IP address you use when you remotely connect to your home network (favorite coffee shop IP, Workplace IP, Mobile Phone IP...)
- The odd events occurred at time xx:xx, is there any entries in the router's log corresponding approximately to this time, or few hours before ?

**iMac & Minimac:** You first need to find a suspicious entry in the router's log, note this suspicious entry **timestamp** somewhere, then search in the Mini-mac's system.log what occurred at this **time**. Do the same process with your iMac via `sudo last username` command.

> How would I be able to retrieve more items for last command?

Let me introduce you a famous acronym in the IT world, called **RTFM** : Read the **Fine** Manual. [look here](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/last.1.html)

Comment: In router logs, there were entries similar to this one:

`[LAN access from remote] from 169.53.184.23:38990 to 192.168.1.22:8000, Friday, Jun 23,2017 07:03:14
[LAN access from remote] from 169.53.184.23:10000 to 192.168.1.22:8000, Friday, Jun 23,2017 07:03:13`

Comment: I only have system.log on both macs. Also, what specific info should I look for in the system logs?

Comment: As for Last, I get this:

minimac   ttys000                   Fri Jun 23 10:46   still logged in
minimac   console                   Tue Jun 20 23:40   still logged in
reboot    ~                         Tue Jun 20 23:38 
shutdown  ~                         Tue Jun 20 23:37 
minimac   ttys000                   Tue Jun 20 22:50 - 22:50  (00:00)
minimac   ttys000                   Tue Jun 20 22:06 - 22:06  (00:00)
minimac   console                   Tue Jun 20 21:45 - 23:37  (01:51)
reboot    ~                         Tue Jun 20 21:42

Comment: How would I be able to retrieve more items for last command?

Comment: @ogmios , please, check the edit2.